# GCM didn't work

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

GOOGLE Cloud messaging works fine for me. I've sent many push notifications in a day and it works fine suddenly it stop sending me notification next day.It's not working anymore not  a single notification after a long delay. What is the issue? Is there any defined limitation about GCM?  Is GCM works for a time being?

Comment: Did it stopped working both when your device is connected by WiFi and data connection? Did you check that your API key is still valid?

Comment: Yes i checked everything API Key sender ID are the same and it was running perfectly before. I didn't change or edit the code and it stopped running immediately. I test it again by creating another Gmail account. It again worked fine but stopped suddenly. I made update&time_to_live=0&delay_while_idle=0. coz i wanted to have push notifications without any delay.

Comment: It's working now. May be there were server down issue that GCM may down temporarily. Hope the issue is not arisen so often.